# Vector of pair of pairs?

Tags: vector, key-value, std-pair

Is it possible to make a vector of pair of pairs of two integers?or else can you suggest a way to create a structure where there is four attributes of each member and needs to sort based on the first one , in case of equality the second and so on..

Comment: Have you tried? If yes, please show the code that isn't working, including all error messages and other relevant information for a [mre]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.